# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace') just after deployment, no errors locally

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vercel

I've deployed a project to Vercel and, since it's deployed, it loads only a totally black screen with console telling me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')".

In my code, which is a social media app, I call replace when a post is created or updated, not before logging into it. Besides, this doesn't happen locally, just when it's deployed. Any guesses what this is about?

As example, this is where I use replace():

```
export async function createPost(post: INewPost) {
  try {
    // Upload file to appwrite storage
    const uploadedFile = await uploadFile(post.file[0]);

    if (!uploadedFile) throw Error;

    // Get file url
    const fileURL = getFilePreview(uploadedFile.$id);
    if (!fileURL) {
      await deleteFile(uploadedFile.$id);
      throw Error;
    }

    // Convert tags into array
    const tags = post.tags?.replace(/ /g, "").split(",") || [];

    // Create post
    const newPost = await databases.createDocument(
      appwriteConfig.databaseID,
      appwriteConfig.postCollectionID,
      ID.unique(),
      {
        creator: post.userID,
        caption: post.caption,
        imageURL: fileURL,
        imageID: uploadedFile.$id,
        location: post.location,
        tags: tags,
      }
    );

    if (!newPost) {
      await deleteFile(uploadedFile.$id);
      throw Error;
    }

    return newPost;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Just to get my conscience clean as well I tried switching away from Vercel but nothing changed at all.

Answer (score 1):

To Ensure that the `replace` and `split` function should performed when `post.tags` is defined

Change the following line -

`const tags = post.tags?.replace(/ /g, "").split(",") || [];`

to -

`const tags = post.tags ? post.tags.replace(/ /g, "").split(",") : [];`

**I hope this helps you identify whether the error lies in the conditions or in the data you are setting , have a good day !**

Comment: Okay, the error still the same, but I mean, it makes sense. When you load up the site for the first time you don't have to load post tags... Why this happens on deployment?

Comment: const tags = (post.tags || '').replace(/ /g, "").split(",") || [];
Try this and if you can elaborate the code then it will help me more to logically solve this issue.

Comment: That didn't work either. This tags const actually is when a post is being updated or created, but it gives me errors only on deploy and when the site just shows up, it's weird

Comment: Can you upload your code somewhere , where I can try to sort this out because it can also occur through data that can't use replace or split function in it . So share me link where I can see you project clearly with dummy data to it .

Comment: Sure thing. Here's the whole code: https://github.com/caiohportella/snapgram

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at Client.setEndpoint (appwrite.js?v=cd59b77e:707:89)
    at config.ts:15:8

I am getting this error while running the code locally , I think env file is not there am i right ?

Comment: oh yeah, there's no .env due to the keys... Is there any way still?

Comment: Sorry but I can't check without running and analysing the code .

Comment: I've made a new commit, check it out

Comment: Just found out the issue! The environment variables weren't configured inside Vercel, thus the error. After I added them to the project settings it works fine. Thanks for the patience, your time and your help!